# Can $X^2+Y^2-1$ be factored?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

Prove geometrically that $X^2+Y^2-1$ cannot be factored. I have proved it algebraically but I don't have any idea how to prove it geometrically. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If it factors, then what are the degrees of the factors?  What does that mean for the zero-set?

Comment: Both the factors should be of the form $aX+bY+c.$ Am I right?

Comment: So they represent points on a straight line.

Comment: Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be the lines then zeros of $X^2+Y^2-1$ is the union of zeros of $L_1$ and $L_2.$

Comment: Right.  So is it really?

Comment: But two straight lines cut the unit circle in at most two points.

Comment: If it were true then circle would have at most four points on it.

Comment: I think the argument your looking for is rather "But the unit circle is not the union of two straight lines".

Comment: Right. That would be more precise, I would say.